# LayoutInflater имеет какое-то отношение к внешнему виду view?

Tags: java, android

Цель проста - подгружать в listView данные с БД через кастомный адаптер.

Написал простенький адаптер, решил запустить и проверить все ли работает и удивился, view-элементы изменили внешний вид, в layout файле все стандартно, при использовании родного адаптера тоже все нормально. Я заменил одну строчку, и внешний вид нормализовался, но я не понимаю как она имеет к нему отношение.

Ненормальный вн. вид был с : `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

До:

[image: ДО]

Решение проблемы: `LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();`

После:

[image: После]

```
private class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
    Context context;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    MyAdapter(Context context,int resourceID,Cursor cursor,String[] from,int[]to,int flags){
        super(context,resourceID,cursor,from,to,flags);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(row==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
            holder.name= (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            holder.days = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvDays);
            holder.hours = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvHours);
            holder.minutes = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvMinutes);
            holder.seconds = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvSeconds);
            holder.start = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btStart);
            holder.stop = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btStop);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.btStart:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Start pressed "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.btStop:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Start pressed "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        holder.start.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        holder.stop.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        return row;
    }
    class ViewHolder{
        TextView name,days,hours,minutes,seconds;
        Button start,stop;
    }
}
```

В интернете я не нашел ответа на этот вопрос, может кто-то сталкивался и может рассказать о этом явлении.

Comment: Возможно, дело в темах Активити/приложения, кои в манифесте указаны...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Тут секрет заключается в том, что элементы при создании получают набор атрибутов из текщуей темы. Тема ассоциируется с контекстом, поэтому в зависимости от того, какой берётся контекст, меняется и тема. Для активности задана светлая тема, а для контекста приложения - тёмная, поэтому в первом случае, когда берётся контекст приложения, элементы создаются, как будто фон тёмный, а во втором - с учётом светлого.